# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery when using SUM in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This SQL query fails when i try and do a

"WHEN SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(second, t.Start, t.Finish ) / 3600.0)) > 8"

in my Case Statement.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeNumber, e.FirstName, e.LastName, cast(t.DateWorked as date) as DateWorked,
SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(second, t.Start, t.Finish ) / 3600.0)) as HoursWorked,
SUM(CASE 
-- #Check for overtime# HoursWorked > DailyHours
WHEN SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(second, t.Start, t.Finish ) / 3600.0)) > 8
    THEN 
        1
ELSE
        0
END) as moneyEarned
FROM Timesheets t, Employees e
WHERE cast(t.DateWorked as date) BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
AND t.IsDeleted = 0
AND t.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
AND t.FarmId = @farmid
GROUP BY e.EmployeeNumber, e.FirstName, e.LastName, cast(t.DateWorked as date)
```

Is there a way that i could access "HoursWorked" as a variable in my Case statement?

Currently i am getting a "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." error.

Any pointers of how i could approach this differently would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `sum()` inside a `sum()` and this is not allowed.  Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeNumber, e.FirstName, e.LastName,
       cast(t.DateWorked as date) as DateWorked,
       SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(second, t.Start, t.Finish ) / 3600.0)) as HoursWorked,
       (CASE -- #Check for overtime# HoursWorked > DailyHours
             WHEN SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(second, t.Start, t.Finish ) / 3600.0)) > 8
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END) as moneyEarned
. . .
```

You should also learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.